# Find $n$ vertices in complete graph with maximal edge sum

Tags: graph-theory, optimization, discrete-optimization

Suppose that I have a weighted complete graph $G$ with $N$ vertices. Is there a way to find (at least approximately) precisely $n \leq N$ vertices such that the sum of the weights of all their connecting edges is maximal?

First I thought that this may be some kind of Steiner tree, but I don't think that's the case.

Thanks!

Edit: by "maximal" I mean that I want to find vertices such that the sum of the weights of all edges that connect them is maximal, i.e. we can find no other set of vertices with a larger such sum.

As a simple example, suppose we have a (complete) graph of 4 vertices, 1, 2, 3 and 4, with weights $w_{12} = 0, w_{13} = 1 ,w_{14} = 2, w_{23} = 3, w_{24} = 4, w_{34} = 5$ and we want to pick 3 vertices with maximal sum as above, then we would pick the vertices 2, 3 and 4, since their sum would be $w_{23}+w_{24}+w_{34}=12$, which is larger than any other such sum

Comment: what you mean by "maximal"?

Comment: @Exodd I've edited my post to explain further.

Comment: Then the answer is: if you find a way, tell me first, since it is a NP-complete problem

Comment: Hmm that's what I thought. Was hoping for some nice approximative approach.

Comment: From here https://dimacs11.zib.de/workshop/ElKebirKlau.pdf t seems the problem is hard to approximate even by a constant factor

Comment: Okay interesting! Though it seems that this is for node weighted graphs. Is there a nice invertible transformation which takes edge weighted graphs to node weighted graphs, and vice versa?

Answer (score 1):

This is the *maximum edge-weight clique* (MEWC) problem.  You can solve it via integer linear programming as follows.  Let binary decision variable $x_i$ indicate whether node $i$ is selected.  Let binary decision variable $y_{i,j}$ indicate whether edge $\{i,j\}$ is selected.  The problem is to maximize $\sum_{i,j} w_{i,j} y_{i,j}$ subject to
\begin{align}
\sum_i x_i &= n \tag1\\
y_{i,j} &\le x_i &&\text{for all $i<j$} \tag2\\
y_{i,j} &\le x_j &&\text{for all $i<j$} \tag3
\end{align}
Constraint $(1)$ selects exactly $n$ nodes.
Constraints $(2)$ and $(3)$ enforce $y_{i,j} \implies (x_i \land x_j)$.